# update panel causing full post in remote server

Tags: c#-3.0

i have a updatepanel in my page working fine locally in IIS 5.1 but when i move the page to the remote server the updatepanel causing fullpostback what is the problem? In the remote server we have IIS 6. I built the page using VS2008 framework.

any suggestion to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

The slightest mistake in syntax or set up can make the UpdatePanel behave in unusual ways. I'd suggest copying the page and cropping out portions that you deem irrelevant to the functionality until all you're left with is the bare essentials required to function (not display) as expected. If you still have problems at that point you should post your code.